# How to place css and html files in single directory in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am working on a django web application where users login to the application and create web pages. Each page can have different themes, just like a wordpress themes.

Problem:

I am able to create themes(templates) and dynamically load them depending upon the user choice. My problem is all the css and html files of a single theme are not located in single folder.

css files are in `static` directory and html are in `templates` directory.

I want to segregate these files. I want to create a single directory called 'Themes' in which multiple directories will be there for each theme like `theme A` and `theme B`. In each theme directory again there will be `css`,`js` and also `html` directories.  How to implement these and load them?

EDITED:

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'social_django.context_processors.backends',
            'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
        ],
    },
},
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "our_static"),
]
```

Comment: Can you provide a copy of your settings.py?

Comment: @EndersonMenezes, please check added settings.py

Comment: Did you try rename static_root directory to same directory of DIRS? And you can control this with routes and models for each user, would need to understand a little more of its structure.